# Nuxt acces vuex store inside mixin

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js, store

I m making small mixin for driving animations based on how user is crawling through page and I need to have access to data stored in Vuex store from that mixin.
Any ides how to pass data from vuex store there, I am getting mad.

pages/index.vue

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import {ToplevelAnimations} from '~/mixins/toplevel_animations'

export default Vue.extend({

    mixins: [
       ToplevelAnimations
    ]
        
})
```

mixins/toplevel_animations.js

```
 export const ToplevelAnimations = {

    transition(to, from) { 
        // some logic, here I need to access routes stored in store
        return (to_index < from_index ? 'switch-to-left' : 'switch-to-right');
    }
   
}
```

store/index.js

```
import {StoreExtensions} from "~/plugins/store_extensions.js";

export const state = () => ({

    MAIN_NAV_LINKS: [
        {
            path: '/',
            title: 'Domov',
            order: 1
        },
        // ...etc
    ],

    CURRENT_PAGE_INDEX: 1

})

export const getters = {

    getMainNavLinks: (state, getters) => {
        return state.MAIN_NAV_LINKS
    }
    // ..etc
}

export const mutations = {

    setCurrentPageIndex(index) {
        state.CURRENT_PAGE_INDEX = index
    } 
    // ...etc
}

export const actions = {
  
  nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, req ) {
    var page_index = StoreExtensions.calculatePageIndex(req.route.path, state.MAIN_NAV_LINKS)
    mutations.setCurrentPageIndex(page_index)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used `Vue.extend()`, always using .vue files, so it might be different (although it should not). From my experience with mixins in both Vue and Nuxt seems that mixins receive the relevant `this` context when they are assigned to components. So for me using simple `this.$store` worked.